# Seat heater fuse at 12V even when ignition is off?

Tags: honda, fuse, odyssey, seat

I'm looking for a fuse in my 2015 Honda Odyssey that is 0v when ignition is off. I thought the passenger side seat heater should be the one but I tested 12 V when ignition is off. Is this normal?

Comment: If your adding a circuit to the car you should probably have some kind of relay setup. Use the ignition circuit for pin 85 and pin 30 could go straight to the battery with an inline fuse.

Answer (score 6):

There are three fuses for the seat heater system

1) Passenger fuse box:  Fuse 20, 7.5 amp. Supplies Seat heater control unit.

2) Passenger fuse box:  Fuse 5, 15 amp. Supplies relay power pin.

3) Driver side fuse box: Fuse 26, 7.5 amp. Supplies to relay control coil.

Some have power key off, some do not.

Comment: 5 is hot all the time, 20 and 26 are hot key on.

Comment: They are all hot at all time... Couldn't find a single fuse I the passenger side that's not hot all yime